# How do I fix error 4112 in Rosetta Stone?

Tags: windows, rosetta-stone

[Error 4112 shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpfWc.jpg) when I select my language level. (German 1 or French 1)

I think it's also like this for the other levels.

[image]

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you talk to their support?

Comment: Couldn't reach them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erorr 4112 can be fixed, it indicates that **the language file is corrupted**.

The only fix I could thus suggest is to **reinstall the languge file** (and software) to get rid of corruption...

<sub>Heh... I should get back to practice Italian with Rosetta Stone, long time ago.</sub>

Comment: God, I reinstalled and now I have another error when I try to add the language packs: Error 9118

Comment: @ChristianM: Sorry, we can't keep helping you solve different errors that have no meaning to us. Please take time to Google for them to see if you can find an explanation, as far as I did I didn't see anything useful reagirding that error. The only thing that can still help is the Rosetta Stone Support or any log files that the application creates, you might also consider trying to install the software on a different computer to see if there is something wrong with your Windows installation instead. Yes, their language system isn't written that good, had similar issues but reinstalling worked.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't give more information on the errors! Anyway, I found version 3.4.5 on TPB and it's working fine. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just run it as Admin

if this didn't work then go to C/programdata/rosettastone and backup tracking.db3 to your desktop,and delete the original then run the program as Admin, then close it then delete the new tracking.db3 and replace it with the one you back upped in your desktop and voile!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob. Since there's very little on the internet, I've pasted the gist of the live chat that helped me resolve the issue below.

> Me: Hello. Thanks for helping me today. I have Espanol LA 1,2, and 3
>   on Windows 7. I am getting error code 4112 after I try to load my
>   already activated and updated product. I tried uninstalling and
>   reinstalling and I am still getting 4112.
>
> Tech: Click on Start->Click on Computer->Click on C:   Do you see
>   program data folder?
>
> Me: no
>
> Tech: Then click on the organize on the top. Then click on folder and
>   search options. Then click on the view tab.
>
> Me: ah. show hidden files folders and drives
>
> Tech: Yes. Have a check on it, click ok. Now you can see program data.
>
> Me: now i'm able to get into program data, rosetta stone, then Totale
>
> Me: now i see the file dynamic stored paths
>
> Tech: Delete dynamic stored paths in Rosetta stone and TOTALe folder
>
> Me: done
>
> Tech: Close all the windows and open the program
>
> Tech: Do not click on any user name. Insert the language level cd in
>   the drive.
>
> Tech: Please click on the icon next to the question mark with small
>   lines
>
> Me: yes
>
> Tech: you can close the windows which shows the files of the cd.
>
> Tech: Click on add/remove languages
>
> Tech: Click on add a language level
>
> Tech: right. done. Now it says: A newer version of this language level
>   already exists on your computer. Are you sure you want to overwrite?
>
> Me: Perhaps it's just referring to updates that were made when I had
>   installed it before?
>
> Tech: Yes. Over write
>
> Me: installing
>
> Tech: Install all three levels with your three discs and their updates